​Warum steht ein Verb am Anfang dieses Hauptsatzes?
Aus Qualityland von Marc-Uwe Kling:

Als Tony Parteichef die Bühne in der Zentrale der Fortschrittspartei
betritt, fühlt er förmlich, wie die Scheinwerfer den übermächtigen
Schatten seines Vaters von ihm nehmen. Zeitlebens hat er daran
gearbeitet. Keine leichte Aufgabe, war sein Vater doch bekanntermaßen
der Mann, der dem Land seinen Namen gegeben hat.

Die fettgedruckte Wortreihenfolge ist verwirrend. Ich würde denken, dass der Satz, der mit "war sein Vater" beginnt, ein eigener Hauptsatz wäre und die entsprechende Wortreihenfolge benutzen müsste - also, Verb in der zweiten Position: "Sein Vater war...".
Die in der Tat gebrauchte Reihenfolge würde für mich nur Sinn machen, wenn "Keine leichte Aufgabe" so betrachtet würde, Teil von diesem Hauptsatz zu sein und die erste Position zu besetzen. Das macht für mich aber keinen Sinn, denn ich halte "Keine leichte Aufgabe" quasi für einen verkürzten Hauptsatz - also, eine Verkürzung von "Das war keine leichte Aufgabe" oder Ähnlichem, oder einfach eine getrennte Bemerkung, die jedenfalls die erste Position nicht füllt.
Erklärt mir das mal, wenn ihr könnt!

Das ist leider nicht erklärbar, sondern konventionell... vgl. ganze Liste von V1-Nebensatzfunktionen in https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/V1-Stellung#V1-Stellung_in_Nebens%C3%A4tzen

Dabei handelt es sich um einen uneingeleiteten Kausalsatz.
Ein Kausalsatz ist ein Satz, der eine Begründung für einen Sachverhalt beinhaltet.
Kausalsätze können Hauptsätze aber auch Nebensätze sein, je nachdem, wie sie eingeleitet werden:

kausale Nebensatzkonstruktionen (Verb am Ende):

Das war keine leichte Aufgabe, weil sein Vater doch bekanntermaßen dieser Mann war.
Das war keine leichte Aufgabe, da sein Vater doch bekanntermaßen dieser Mann war.
Das war keine leichte Aufgabe, zumal sein Vater doch bekanntermaßen dieser Mann war.


kausale Hauptsatzkonstruktion (Verb an Position 2) (standardsprachlich):

Das war keine leichte Aufgabe, denn sein Vater war doch bekanntermaßen dieser Mann.


alternative kausale Hauptsatzkonstruktion (Verb an Position 2) (nicht standardsprachlich, wird aber gelegentlich umgangssprachlich verwendet):

Das war keine leichte Aufgabe, weil sein Vater war doch bekanntermaßen dieser Mann.



Eine weitere Variante ist der Kausalsatz, der ohne eine Einleitung durch eine Konjunktion gebildet wird. Diese Konstruktion gehört zu den Ausnahmen, wo das Verb an Position 1 steht, denn hier übernimmt das Verb die Rolle des einleitenden Wortes:

Das war keine leichte Aufgabe, war sein Vater doch bekanntermaßen dieser Mann.

Eine weitere Besonderheit dieser Konstruktion ist die Tatsache, dass sie ohne das Wort »doch« nicht funktioniert:

falsch: Das war keine leichte Aufgabe, war sein Vater bekanntermaßen dieser Mann.

In allen oben angegebenen Beispielen, in denen der Kausalsatz durch ein Bindewort eingeleitet wird, hat »doch« die Funktion einer Modalpartikel und kann ohne Änderung der Aussage des Satzes weggelassen werden. In der uneingeleiteten Version ist »doch« zwar weiterhin ebenfalls eine Modalpartikel, kann aber trotzdem nicht weggelassen werden, weil die Konstruktion sonst nicht funktionieren würde.

Ergänzung (nicht mehr Teil der eigentlichen Antwort):
Der Teil »Keine leichte Aufgabe« ist eine Ellipse, die weder ein Subjekt noch ein Verb enthält. Trotzdem ist sie genau jener (unvollständige) Hauptsatz, der den Sachverhalt beinhaltet, dessen Begründung in dem hier diskutierten Kausalsatz steht. In meinen Beispielen habe ich diese Ellipse mit einem naheliegenden Subjekt (dem Relativpronomen »das«) und einem ebenfalls naheliegenden Verb (»war«) zu einem vollständigen Hauptsatz ergänzt.

Man kann statt doch z.B. auch ja oder gar ein Adverbial wie vor ihm einsetzen. Da spielt irgendeine Rhythmusregel hinein.

@Janka: Im Fall der Partikel »ja« stimme ich dir zu, aber »vor ihm« anstelle von »doch« überzeugt mich nicht.
